# Tub and sink faucet damage

Tags: faucet, finish

My sink and bathtub faucets both had a lot of water deposits on them, so I put white vinegar in bags and used rubber bands to secure those to the faucets and left them there for a few hours. When I returned, the dark brown metal faucets had a sort of plastic peeling off of them and the dark color is going everywhere. I am assuming that plastic stuff is the finish? Is it safe to keep using those faucets? It isn't really affordable right now to replace them, but I don't want to release toxins or anything like that into the water.

Comment: Pictures are always a good idea so we can see what you see.

Comment: Peel/remove all the loose covering.  Vinegar and similar stuff is more of wipe on/wipe off, maybe a couple of minutes for tough stains.

Comment: Many faucet/sink metal-looking parts are now "clear coated" with a paint/plastic-like clear protective finish rather than just being metal on the surface. Although it is tough, it can be scratched or otherwise damaged. Sounds like the vinegar reacted badly with the clear coat in your case. I'd call the manufacturer about the issue.  You may be able to remove the faucet handles and spray paint them with an automotive clear coat to at least stop the metal underneath from leaching whatever is leaching.

Comment: what kind of vinegar did you use ? the low concentration food vinegar or the high concentration type (30%)

Comment: It was just the regular distilled while vinegar you can get from a grocery store. It wasn't anything with a high concentration. It think it was the plastic-like finish that Armand mentioned that peeled off. I will try to figure out who the manufacturer is to contact them. I don't see a logo or anything on the outside, but if I can remove the faucets, maybe there will be one on the inside? They were installed prior to me buying the house, so I don't have any paperwork on them.

Comment: For the sake of $£€ 1.50 vs $£€ 0.25, don't use vinegar for descaling visible structures like faucets/taps. It's just not worth it. Spray-on descalers are designed  not to damage the substrate.